# Autocomplete jquery ui feed by function don't run

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">  
</head>
<body>
  <label for="search">Tags: </label>
  <input id="search" placeholder="Pelicula" autofocus> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this autocomplete script runs properly:

$(function() {

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source:  ["paco", "pablo", "pedro", "pepe"]
  }
});
```

});

But then, I feed the autocomplete with a function that returns the same array, and the autocomplete crashes:

$(function() {

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(){
    return ["paco", "pablo", "pedro", "pepe"];
  }
});
```

});

I don't see any sense in it. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: Im doing this because I want to change after the function to return an array with values from a query json+ajax from an api.

Comment: Try destroying it first before you load it up again. `$('#search").autocomplete("destroy");`

Comment: @user3158900 It keeps crashing

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  It was taken from the documentation.

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var tags = ["paco", "pablo", "pedro", "pepe"];
        var matcher = new RegExp( '^' + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), 'i');
        response( $.grep(tags, function(item) {
            return matcher.test( item );
        }) );
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's getting called before the other one.  Try removing the first line.  It's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this and it runs:

```
$(function() {
arr = getTags();

$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source: arr
});

function getTags(){
  return ["paco", "pablo", "pedro", "pepe"];
}
```

});